# Implement variable attribute property observer in Swift

Tags: swift, attributes, didset

I want to implement a `didSet` over a "sub-attribute" of a variable.

Example:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
var myLabel.hidden { didSet{ "DO SOMETHING" } }
```

I want to hide/show some other views when `myLabel.hidden` attribute change.
How can I do it?

Comment: Use KVC since UILabel implements NSObject.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a property like this

```
    var hideLabel: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        myLabel.isHidden = hideLabel
        //SHOW OR HIDE OTHER VIEWS
    }
}
```

By doing this you don't have to use KVO at the same time you can add more controls to hide to show at didSet context.
I Believe this is a simpler way to do such a thing.

Answer (score 2):

The standard process is to use KVO. Add observer when the view is loaded:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    label.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "hidden", options: .New | .Old, context: nil)
}
```

When the view controller is deallocated, make sure to remove the observer.

```
deinit {
    label.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "hidden")
}
```

And do whatever you want inside the `observeValueForKeyPath` method:

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    NSLog("\(change)")

    // do whatever you want here
}
```

Comment: I get an exception in the `deinit`, my `label` is `nil`! I have my `UIViewController` inside a Tab controller

Comment: Yep, w tab bar controller you might instantiate view controller, but never load the view. So you'd check to see if it's `nil` or not before trying to call `removeObserver`.

Answer (score 1):

Property observers can only be added to a class, not an instance. In order to do this you need to subclass `UILabel` and then override `hidden`'s property observers.

EDIT: If you want to set custom observers on instances of CustomLabel, you can do this easily by adding block function variables to your CustomLabel that trigger on `didSet` or `willSet`

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel {

    var onDidSetHidden: ((Bool) -> ())?
    var onWillSetHidden: ((Bool) -> ())?

    override var hidden: Bool {
        didSet {
            if let block = onDidSetHidden {
                block(self.hidden)
            }
        }

        willSet (willBeHidden) {
            if let block = onWillSetHidden {
                block(willBeHidden)
            }
        }
    }
}

var custom = CustomLabel()
custom.onDidSetHidden = { (isHidden) in
    if isHidden {
        println("IS HIDDEN")
    } else {
        println("IS NOT HIDDEN")
    }
}

custom.hidden = true //prints 'IS HIDDEN'
```

Comment: It will be cool if I can add those observers to instance variables

Comment: If you're willing to subclass UILabel you can do this with a workaround. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah but with this approach I cant modify my UIViewController properties on that event

Comment: Sure you can--but if you're triggering if from your view controller you have use `self` within the closure to refer to the view controller instance